BigQuery permissions/access
I need to update data in BigQuery. Data comes from CRM by API . I didn't set up this connection, so I don't understand, what's wrong.
When I try to update Data by running code (python) , I recieve the error:
Error during uploading to BigQuery: 403 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{{project_name}}/jobs?prettyPrint=false
I have such permissions:

IAM - BigQuery Admin ;
service Account - Service Account Admin .

BigQuery API is enable. Keys are actual.
May be you know, what should I do in this situation.

Can you share some more details, please? It would help a great deal if we could see the Python code that you are running and also a more complete error message.

403 very likely means that the caller requesting the operation is not authorized.  As Paddy says, we need a lot more detail.  What was the EXACT command/statement being executed?  What were the parameters?  What was the full/exact error?  Who are you running as?  What roles does the caller possess?  For each of the resources, what roles have been granted to the user for each resource?
